# linux firefox flash debug: i don't get alerts when errors occur

Tags: firefox, flash, debug

I use firefox 3.6.13 on linux gentoo amd64 and flash 10.2 debug version,
i also have firebug flashbug and flashfirebug installed.

my problem is that whenever I run a flash application that encounters an error, the browser does not open an alert window. it makes it more difficult to debug  applications because i need to make sure that the firebug window is always opened. the only way i can see the error is if i open the flash tab in firebug. is there a way to change this behavior ?

i checked .xsession-errors and tried running firefox from console:
these are the only errors the i see in the log and these errors do not appear when the flash app encounters an error which means they are not related:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module": libcanberra-gtk-module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gnomebreakpad": libgnomebreakpad.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your ~/.xsession-errors ?

How do you start firefox? Clicking on an icon?

Try starting it on a console. Don't you get error messages there?

Comment: updated main post. i didn't see any relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the corresponding dbg packages? If you want to use a debugger you will have to install the corresponding debug symbols. Thus if you want to use a debugger on firefox install the firefox-dbg package, too. At least that is the case with ubuntu.

Comment: as i mentioned in the topic i have flash debug version install, when i right click on a flash file i have a debugger menu item.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo "GTK_MODULE=/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/modules/" > /etc/env.d/51gtk2
```

then reboot.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific with your detail, consider adding some reference and proof supporting what you state, and confirming this answer is not already answered in one of the existing answers on the post if applicable.